# Why is uninterruptible sleep indicated by 'D'?

Tags: process, io, history

From "man ps":

```
R = Running or Runnable
S = interruptable Sleep
T = sTopped
Z = Zombie

D = uninterruptible sleep (usually IO)
```

Where does this D come from?

Comment: "D"ormant comes to mind

Comment: _D_isk, I believe

Comment: @JeffSchaller with all due respect, not all I/O is "disk" bound.

Comment: @Mel - granted; Disk is just my mnemonic for it. This Q might benefit from a 'history' tag, as it may have just been down to the most reasonable remaining choice by the 'ps' programmer.

Comment: @MelBurslan Nonetheless, that's where it comes from. (“Device” would be more technically accurate but not historically correct).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [4BSD ps man page](http://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=4BSD/usr/man/cat1/ps.1):

> The state is given by a sequence of
>   four letters, e.g. ``RWNA''.  The first letter indicates the
>    runnability of the process: R for runnable processes, T for
>    stopped processes, P for processes in page wait, **D for those
>    in disk (or other short term) waits**, S for those sleeping
>    for less than about 20 seconds, and I for idle (sleeping
>    longer than about 20 seconds) processes.